# How does a fumble at kickoff or a punt - recovered by kicking team - affect win conditions in overtime?

Tags: rules, american-football, nfl

In the NFL, Overtime conditions state that if the team to possess the ball first score a Touchdown on their first possession, then they win the game. If they score a Field Goal, or fail to score, then the other team has a chance to possess the ball.

Now let's look at the following examples:

Team A has won the toss in overtime and has elected to receive the kickoff. Team B kicks the ball and it is returned by Team A. During the return, the runner fumbles the ball and it is recovered by a member of Team B.

**Does Team B need to score a Touchdown or a Field Goal to win the game?** As they are the first team to run a down.

---

Similarly...

It is 4th down for Team A, on the first possession of overtime, and they decide to Punt. Team A punts the ball down the field. A fair-catch is called, but the returner from Team B does not cleanly collect the ball, and muffs it. It is then recovered by Team A.

**Does Team A still need to score a Touchdown to win the game, or do they now only require a Field Goal?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both scenarios only a **Field Goal** is required to win the game. This is because it is deemed that the receiving team in both instances has had their opportunity to possess the ball.

From the [2019 NFL Rulebook: Rule 16 - Section 1 - Article 3](https://operations.nfl.com/the-rules/2019-nfl-rulebook/#article-3.-extra-period)

> **Article 3. Extra Period**
>
> [...]
>
> (e) The opportunity to possess applies only during kicking plays. A kickoff is the opportunity to possess for the receiving team. **If the kicking team legally recovers the kick, the receiving team is considered to have had its opportunity. A punt or field goal attempt that crosses the line of scrimmage and is muffed by the receiving team is considered to be an opportunity to possess for the receiving team.** Normal touching rules by the kicking team apply.